# Regex line by line

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list

```
import re

P = re.compile(r'(?<=\{\n)((.*\n)*)(?=\})', re.MULTILINE)

text = r'''title {
      P 01
      X 02
    }'''
re.findall(P, text)
```

With this code I grep everything between brackets but as a single element.

How can I get a list with single line element like:

```
['P 01', 'X 02']
```

Comment: Split your resulting match, `re.search(P, text).group().splitlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
import re

P = re.compile(r'\{(.*?)}', re.DOTALL)

text = r'''title {
      P 01
      X 02
    }'''
x = re.search(P, text)
if x:
    print([z.strip() for z in x.group(1).strip().splitlines()])
```

**Result**: `['P 01', 'X 02']`

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##NY3BCsIwEETv@xV7SyIltHoTRASPBXvwIKgHKakNtElIVqgt/fbYVt3LDDOPWfem2ppNjLp11hN6BVDgblJZ2tbpRnHPbgOXq70YWTLnx9P5kOcCgFRHM8oYI02NwgFwuQLT7GcvmK4XO04UdN/loB6@rHmR4DwhQFfYbRfKeW2IX3sZyGvHBVbWY4/aYCef3r4cz8S/k8E101ttVODiLiDGDw).